# How do i randomly choose 2 instances ( 2 rows) for testing & remaining for training in a dataset

Tags: python, r

How do I randomly choose 2 instances ( 2 rows ) for testing & remaining for training in a sample dataset like this.

```
dog.data

22.0,4566.0,56.4,89.3,Dog-fifota
81.0,3434.0,34.4,67.3,Dog-listem
30.0,8944.0,23.4,45.3,Dog-biker
55.0,3455.0,78.5,11.3,Dog-listem
41.4,3345.0,45.3,34.1,Dog-fifota
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The data you show is three rows and 5 columns, so it's hard to know where 10 columns will come from in that kind of dataset. Do you want a random sample of the data, or something else? What code have you written to handle your data so far?

Comment: Why is this tagged `r`?

Comment: @Blckknght I just edited the question.

Comment: @nrussell  I am trying to write an R function to split up this dataset into training and testing sets

Comment: But you have 4 numeric columns and 1 character, you want to treat them the same way??

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes. I want to treat them the same way.

Comment: Do you really mean columns, or you actually want rows?

Comment: Oh well you should probably include the R code from your attempted solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry,my bad. When I say instances,  I actually want the rows. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try (in R)

```
indx <- sample(nrow(dog.data), 2) 
test <- dog.data[indx, ] 
train <- dog.data[-indx, ]
```

---

**Edit**

If you want it as a function, something like this would work:

```
spltfunc <- function(x){
  indx <- sample(nrow(x), 2)
  test <- x[indx, ] 
  train <- x[-indx, ]
  list2env(list(test = test, train = train), .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Testing

```
set.seed(123) # setting the random seed so you can reproduce results
spltfunc(dog.data)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
test
#   V1   V2   V3   V4         V5
# 2 81 3434 34.4 67.3 Dog-listem
# 4 55 3455 78.5 11.3 Dog-listem
train
#     V1   V2   V3   V4         V5
# 1 22.0 4566 56.4 89.3 Dog-fifota
# 3 30.0 8944 23.4 45.3  Dog-biker
# 5 41.4 3345 45.3 34.1 Dog-fifota
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to split up a data set between a random sample and the rest is to shuffle the whole dataset and then slice. You'll get two randomly ordered lists of items.

Here's a Python function that does that:

```
import random

def split_test_training(data, num_test_rows):
    data_copy = list(data)           # shallow copy
    random.shuffle(data)             # reorder the copied list in-place

    testing = data[:num_test_rows]   # slice the first num_test_rows for testing
    training = data[num_test_rows:]  # slice the rest for training

    return testing, training
```

If you don't mind the passed in list being shuffled by the function, you could skip the shallow copy.